# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' message between website on IIS on Server 2019 and SQL Server 2019 CU1

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis, windows-authentication

We're trying to deploy a new internal website and having got the site working fine with Windows Authentication in Test, we're trying to do the same thing in production but we're getting the old 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' logon failure messages. The only difference between Test and Prod is that the IIS parts on a separate App server for Prod, whereas test has everything on the same server.

Here is what I've tried so far but still getting the same error:
On the web.config file on the app server, the following code is already present to get the app to work with windows auth in the first place:

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <allow roles="domain\ADGroupName"/>
    <Deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Windows Authentication is enabled in IIS and the app pool has been configured to use the correct service account. We've also set up delegation to the SQL box for the respective service account. We are not currently using TLS1.2 to SQL until we can get this issue resolved.

From browser on my laptop:
[Screenshot of error message in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEhGP.png)

Impersonation is coming through as True in the exception found in event viewer on the app server, along with the correct user and service account: [Exception detail from Event Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl9YG.png)

I've spoken to the external developer about the line of code it mentions in the exception in the browser but he assures me it's nothing to do with the application. I've been all through the infrastructure on our side and am stumped. Does anyone have any ideas of what else I can check?

Comment: is your service account a member of domain\ADGroupName ?

Comment: Hi Mitch. The space is a typo from where I hid the actual AD group name. The service account isn't a member of the AD Group but it does have the same permissions. I have since spoken to an old friend of mine and used Kerberos Configuration manager (free download from microsoft site) to diagnose if the double-hop issue is persisting. Unfortunately, as a DBA, I don't have permissions in AD to rectify this fully, but it showed that even though delegation had been set up on the app server with the service account, it hadn't been set up on the SQL VM, so I'm just waiting for my boss to rectify that

Comment: If it doesn't work, then I'm going to switch SQL from using a local NT SERVICE account to a service account and set the trust up on that to see if it helps. I'll chuck a note on if it helps.

Comment: The ASP config above says deny everyone that isn't a member of the AD group 'ADGroupName'. I would create an AD service account and add it to that group; then impersonate that service account

Answer (score 0):

Specifies the user name to use if impersonate is set to true.

userName and password are stored in clear text in the configuration file. Although IIS will not transmit .config files in response to a user agent request, configuration files can be read by other means, for instance by an authenticated user with proper credentials on the domain that contains the server. For security reasons, the identity section supports storage of encrypted userName and password attributes in the registry.

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=xxx;Password=yyy;
```

Comment: this advice is incorrect. Use windows auth wherever possible

Comment: Do you have a test?

Comment: Hi Samwu. I'm of the opinion to use windows auth whenever I can and I'm steadily weaning everyone off sql logins. From what I have seen, they are inevitably abused. But thanks for commenting anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue turned out to be a conflict with impersonation, rather than a double-hop issue. The app is written in .net so the connection string wasn't visible to me, but my boss was web developer in the past and dug it out. Switching impersonation to false in Web.Config file resolved the issue for us.